# How can I switch root UITabbar from anywhere in app?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

Currently, I have a main `uitabbar` ( root view ) and have 5 tabs in it. If I want to trigger `uitabbar` to switch tab from anywhere in app. How can I do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `present` with full screen without changing rootviewcontroller. also use navigation controller push. don't play with rootviewcontroller use it only while logout app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get a reference to your tab bar controller and do something like this (providing your inside a UIViewController). If you have a custom UITabBarController class replace `as? UITabBarController`  with `as? YourClass`.

```
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController as? UITabBarController {
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a `UIViewController` you can access the `UITabBarController` with:

```swift
self.tabBarController
```

This returns the nearest `UITabBarController` in the hierarchy, or `nil` if there is none.